# PL/Proxy returning Unsupported Type on Stored Procedure Call

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've setup a Stored Procedure in PL/Proxy to make a query, and receive some RECORDs back.

In PL/Proxy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_autocomplete(q text, i_id bigint)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
    CLUSTER 'autocompletecluster';
    RUN ON i_id;
$$ LANGUAGE plproxy;
```

In each Partition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_autocomplete(q text, i_id bigint)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN EXECUTE q
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT rec;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you've likely guessed, this is hitting a defined SERVER in PGSQL called 'autocompletecluster'. The query string that I'm sending through is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM autocomplete WHERE member_id = :memberId";
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT query_autocomplete('{$sql}',1234");
```

It's returning the following:

```
SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  PL/Proxy function public.query_autocomplete(0): unsupported type
```

The table that query is hitting is defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE autocomplete (
    id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    extra_data hstore,
    username character varying(254),
    member_id bigint
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error strongly suggests that PL/Proxy doesn't support `SETOF RECORD`. Try instead defining your functions to return `autocomplete%rowtype` or, failing that, `RETURNS TABLE (...)` with a matching columns-set.

Comment: Thanks Craig. By "with matching columns-set", do you mean i need to define the fields im expecting back? In my use case, i must avoid any business logic, even what fields to expect, they must live in the sql statement being sent from our application.

Comment: @cody Then I suspect you're not going to be using PL/Proxy for these statements, or are going to have to send them directly without the procedural wrappers. You'd probably need to follow this up further on the pl/proxy mailing list, but I strongly suspect it just doesn't support `record`.

Comment: You are seemingly correct, we've gone through the C in the project, and it looks as though RECORD is not supported, though it suggests in their documentation that it is. Thanks for your help, we've moved back to exploring PGPool-II, I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @cody Please submit a bug report or documentation patch to PL/Proxy too, to save the next person some hassle.